# Spring Logback use of profile

Tags: spring, logback

In logback.xml you can define several `<springProfile>` tags, e.g. `<springProfile name="development">` and `<springProfile name="test">`.

If I have something like this:

```
<springProfile name="development">
          ...
</springProfile>
<springProfile name="development, test">
        ...
</springProfile>
```

Is the "development" profile a union of those two profiles containing "developer", or does the "developer" profile only activate the former or the latter of the profiles?

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568780/4369820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<springProfile name="development">
    <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "development" profile is active -->
</springProfile>
<springProfile name="development, test">
    <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "development" OR "test" profiles are active -->
</springProfile>
```

[source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_profile_specific_configuration)

So the configuration in both would be relevant for `development` profile, but only the latter will be relevant for `test`.